# Lots of php files or one big php file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance, server

I want to know which approach is better in terms of speed and performance when the  site has millions of users making millions of requests per day.

*What is the matter ? - thousands of requests per minute to vote,follow,add to favorite (values are being inserted in mysql table) etc*

*These are only examples real measures are be much higher*

### **Approach 1**

There is one `executeQueries.php` file.
      **executeQueries.php**

```
  <?php
   $action = $_POST['action'];
   switch($action){
      case 'vote':
         #query for inserting vote
      break;
      case 'follow':
         #query for inserting follower
      break;
      case 'favorite':
         #query for inserting favorite
      break;
    }
  ?>
```

### **Approach 2**

There are three files.

**vote.php** , **follow.php** , **favorite.php**

which contains insert individually to their respective tables

Comment: Lots of smaller files is more easily maintained, and that matters a lot more than any performance difference

Comment: Then should i go with approach 2 ? @MarkBaker

Comment: If you're not using an opcode cache, or autoloading, then one large file will probably be nanoseconds faster.... but using an opcode cache and autoloading will give much better performance, especially with lots of smaller files

Comment: And if you're expecting thousands of requests per minute, then you should be using an up-to-date version of PHP with opcode cache anyway

Comment: what is "opcode cache, or autoloading," ? @MarkBaker

Comment: [opcode cache](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/26902267-PHP-Performance-I-Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-OpCode-Caches)

Comment: [autoloading](http://ditio.net/2008/11/13/php-autoload-best-practices/)

Comment: If you're designing a system that needs to be capable of handling thousands of requests per minute, then you really should be familiar with opcode caching and autoloading

Comment: It might be better for server to access more files rather than a big one everytime. Furthermore, php apache will not have to interpret all your PHP code everytime a user wants to vote if you keep it separated.

Comment: @MarkBaker i was using `php 5.4` so i wasnt aware of that fact ! Now i have installed `opcodeCache` with new `php 5.5`

Comment: so i should go with approach 2 @JanLegner ?

Comment: Well, I would totally go with more files (correctly using includes). You will make it also much easier for yourself as @MarkBaker stated.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache + PHP + a PHP caching scheme, there is no performance difference between the approaches.  Whatever PHP file(s) you have will quickly be compiled and cached.  Then, running a PHP file will be essentially the same, whether it does everything or just one thing.  The IF test in the code is insignificant -- connecting to MySQL and doing the UDPATE will be the biggest time consumers.  (I speak from the experience of working for a large Internet company with this configuration for over a decade.)

Ordinary INSERTs/UPDATEs in an ordinary MySQL configuration will stall at about 100 per second because, simply, of spinning disk speeds.  There are many ways around that.  My point here is that the PHP question is *not* your most important question.

Comment: Huh? So wwhat should I do?

Comment: You asked "show I do (1) or (2)" but did not mention options (3) and (4) and (5).  I am saying (3) "it does not matter which of (1) or (2)".  So, flip a coin.  (4) is "it depends" -- but I did not think of any unspoken things that might help with the decision.  (5) -- well, I suspect there is another choice.

Comment: But I am also saying that 1000 qps _may_ be a problem.  And that problem is mostly unrelated to your question of 1 vs 3 PHP files.

Comment: So what's the fix?  if I have things like these...  Obviously I cannot query em together coz one click=1 insert/update

Comment: What would you do in cases like these?  @rickjames

Comment: Please start a new question to talk about high volume UPDATEing of counters.

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830256/high-volume-updating-counters-mysql @rickjames