# High Volume Updating Counters Mysql

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, performance

I have a site which contains a lot of counters tables:

`favorite`,`follow`,`upvote`,`downvote` etc.

Now at each click I am updating/inserting one row in those tables .

### My Structures

**favourite table**

```
user_id|obj_id|time
```

**follow table**

```
user_id|obj_id|time
```

At each click I have to do an update/insert i.e **1 click = 1 ajax request to server = 1 update/insert** this can cause a lot of calls to the Database.

According to Maths *(as much I know)* and taking the least counts:

```
1 click = 1 request
1 million click = 1 million request
100 million click/day 

= 100 million request/day
= 416k request/hour
= 6830 request/min
= 115 request/sec
```

Is  there any better way I can do this ?

Comment: _"100 million click/day"_... you must work for Facebook?! It's not clear what your problem/question is here as you're simply asking: "If I have lots of traffic, how can I deal with it", but you've not provided any code, errors, stats that indicate an actual problem.

Comment: There are ways to reduce calls to your database, it's called message queueing or job queueing. Idea is that you have a process that's able to accept N requests (say, 100) and once it fills its buffer - it updates required tables, or if a specific amount of time passes (say, 60 seconds passed and you haven't filled the buffer - you would still flush it). However, like @Tanner hinted - premature optimization is root of all evil. Do you even need this optimization? 115 req/sec is not that much for a db.

Comment: well @Tanner it originated from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396183/lots-of-php-files-or-one-big-php-file/28803170?noredirect=1#comment45904383_28803170

Comment: "115 req/sec is not that much for a db" then whats too much ? @N.B.

Comment: @SlimShady The link to the other question doesn't clear anything up. How many calls do you actually get to your db a second/minute? Have you monitored performance and noticed issues? Is this all theoretical? Your question is too broad for a clear definitive answer.

Comment: Databases are mostly constrained with the speed of hard disks. 115 requests a second for updating something can be *roughly* translated as 115 input output operations that a hard drive would have to perform. Solid state disks have high I/O rate, for example, [Samsung EVO 840](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/ssd840evo/specifications.html) lists some really high numbers. What you would need to know are the capabilities of your storage device (bandwith, IOPS etc.) in order to accurately determine what you can pull out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you split the client off into a separate machine from the server?  That is a first, minor, step in scaling.

Do you have replication and readonly queries sent to Slaves?  That can allow for unlimited *read* scaling.  (But this does not address the UPDATE question, other than to lighten the load on the Master.)

115 IOPs on a single, spinning, disk will pretty much saturate it.  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit defaults to 1, which leads to at least 1 IOP per transaction.  Some temporary solutions (until your traffic grows by another 10x)...

SSDs -- maybe 1000 IOPs.

Batch the updates (such as mentioned by @N. B.)  This cuts by 100x the number of "flushes".

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 -- to virtually eliminate the flushes (at some loss of security).

But -- Even if you can do the UPDATEs fast enough, don't you also need to read the values?  That is, there will be contention.  How many SELECTs on the *same* table are you doing?  100/sec might be ok; 1000/sec might cause so much interference that it won't work.

How big is the table?  For any of this to work, it needs to be small enough to be cached all the time.

Reddit is another approach -- capture the updates there.  Then continually pull out accumulated counts and do the needed UPDATEs.

Sharding -- This is where you split up the data across multiple machines.  Splitting on a hash or lookup (or combo of the two) of the userid is common.  Then the UPDATE needs to figure out which machine to update, then perform the action there.  If you have 10 shards (machines), you can sustain nearly 10 times the update rate.  Ultimately, this is the only way that all the heavy hitters can handle 100M+ users and billions of queries/day.

PARTITIONing is not likely to help.  The partition pruning code is not yet efficient enough to avoid too much overhead for such a tiny query.